# query optimization (analytic function)

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have a huge sell table.
In this table we have product and the date where they are sell.
I want to find for each product the 5 last sale.
It's easy to find the query but I want to find one which is fast?
For example:

```
    with foo as
 (select RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY sale_date DESC) RK, p.*
    from sell p)
select * from foo where rk < 6
```

But this query do a full table scan and sort every rows.
So it's not an efficient query.

Any idea to do better?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you look at the explain plan for that query? Do you have indexes on product/sale_date? But, given that you have no where clause in the subquery it probably always will do a full scan, and it cannot avoid the ordering either. Only option I can see is to use dense_rank() or row_number() depending on your requirements. rank() can "skip" numbers. row_number() would give you no more than 5 rows per product. rank() or dense_rank() might give you more than 5.

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer. Yes I have an index on  product/sale_date. I can create any index. But you right, this is not a problem of index. With this query you do a full scan (table or index). The key is to stop searching after 5 rows. Do you think it's possible to do that with row_number or dense_rank? I'll try it soon.

Comment: Get a deck of cards. Remove a few and ignore those. For the rest shuffle and spread face down on a table. Now. Pick 5. Are they the top ranked cards in the deck?  What must you now do to figure out where those 5 cards do rank? Let me know how you go.

Comment: OK, I have one thousand product and hundred billions sale. So to take five thousand rows, I'mm sure, there is an appropriate query or method

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
with foo as (
      select RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY sale_date DESC) as RK,
             p.*
      from sell p
     )
select *
from foo
where rk < 6;
```

can take advantage of an index on `sell(product, sale_date)`.

Comment: Thank for your answer. we have already this index. But oracle do a fast full scan and a sort. So, I'm sure There is a better query to find rows. maybe with lag or row_number and a windows range. But I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You must scan the whole table at some point to satisfy the functional requirement:

> I want to find for each product the 5 last sale.

You won't find a more efficient method that the use of windowing function like `RANK()` however strictly speaking I would use `ROW_NUMBER()` to meet that requirement because `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` can repeat values (so you could potentially get more than 5 rows on a product).

If you can limit the scope of the subquery by date e.g. ignore all sales older than 6 months, then you might avoid a table scan. But as per your description of need, this does no seem to apply. Note that the query optimizer may opt for a table scan if it believes you need such a large portion of the table that it isn't worth using an index.

```
select foo.*
FROM (
      select 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.product ORDER BY s.sale_date DESC) as RN
       , s.*
      from sell s
     ) foo
where foo.rn < 6;
```

I avoid using "cosmetic CTEs" (*CTE used as substitute for derived table subquery*).

Comment: Hi, Thank again for your help. I tried your query, but the plan, the cost and the time duration is exactly the same than mine. So it does not work. Intuitively it could be possible to say " take the five first rows and stop"  if we have an index to sort, isn't it?

Comment: Another thing, excuse me but English is not my natural tongue, so what CTE means?

Comment: Common table expression; `WITH foo AS (...)`